How to Show Spinner while retrieving data?
I use Blazor and .net 7.
I have a Spinner component MyCompanySpinner. I want the spinner will show when a process SetSomething is started and the spinner will hide after the process.
Then the data will shown in the page. Sometimes the process for getting data is a little bit slow. But most of the time not.
@code {
    [Parameter] public int DelayDuration { get; set; } = 200;
    private bool showSpinner = false;
    private bool isInitialized = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Introduce a delay before showing the spinner
        await Task.Delay(DelayDuration);

        Show(); 
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            isInitialized = true;
            Show(); // Show the spinner after initialization
        }
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        if (isInitialized)
        {
            showSpinner = true;
            StateHasChanged(); 
        }
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        if (isInitialized)
        {
            showSpinner = false;
            StateHasChanged(); 
        }
    }

}

@if (showSpinner)
{
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 mb-5">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-rotate-right fa-spin fa-xl pageSpinner" role="status" style="color: #4CAEA8;"></i>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
}

in the razor page:
SetSomething();
    @if (!_showContent)
    {
        <MyCompanySpinner @ref="_spinner" DelayDuration="200" />
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-12">
                <MyCompanyData @ref="MyCompanyRef" SomeData="ViewModel.MyCompanyData" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

in the razor.cs
protected MyCompanySpinner _spinner { get; set; } = new();
protected bool _showContent = false;

protected async Task SetSomething()
{
    //_spinner = new();
    _spinner.Show();

    //Int64 s = 0;
    //for (Int64 i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++)
    //{
    //    s += i;
    //}
    //await Task.Delay(500);

    ViewModel.IBAN = "";
    ViewModel.IbanTenNameVan = "";
    ViewModel.SomethingElse = GetSomethingElse();
    etc...

    _spinner.Hide();
    _showContent = true;
}

I didn't see the spinner. Also when I create a delay (for-loop). When I call the Task.Delay I will see the spinner but I will not see the data.

Does this answer your question? How do I show a loading indicator while images are loading for a Blazor Server application?

If I read your intent correctly, you're overcomplicating this.  I've simplified your code down to provide a minimal working example.
A Spinner Component that either shows a Bootstrap spinner or the content based on a boolean Parameter.
@if(this.Spin)
{
    <div class="m-5 p-5">
        <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    @this.ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Spin { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}

And then a demo Home page to show how it works:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<Spinner Spin="_loading">

    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    Welcome to your new app.
    
    <div class="m-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.OnChangeAsync">Spin Async</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="this.OnChange">Spin Sync</button>
    </div>

</Spinner>


@code{
    private bool _loading;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;
        // First render will occur here as we have yielding async code
        // Fake some async work
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        _loading = false;
    }

    private async Task OnChange()
    {
        _loading = true;
        // Force a yield to update the UI.
        await Task.Delay(1);
        // Fake some sync work
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        _loading = false;
    }

    private async Task OnChangeAsync()
    {
        _loading = true;
        // First render will occur here as we have yielding async code
        // Fake some async work
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        _loading = false;
    }
}

You can tune which bits of the page to put within the spinner, or you could have more that one.

How can I use my Spinner component in your example?

Think about what I've shown you and how you can rebuild your spinner.  You don't need all the show and hide stuff if you let the built in rendering functionality in a component happen.  You don't need a reference to the spinner and call Show and Hide and StateHasChanged.  SetSomething will almost certainly be a Ui event of some sort that will trigger a render.  If the Spin parameter has changed Spinner will be re-rendered as one of it's parameters has changed.  Try it.

First I created a temp project with your code. I didn't see a spinner after clicking a button. Okay then I try it on my own code.
<MyCompanyData @ref="MyCompanyRef" SomeData="ViewModel.MyCompanyData" />
In SetSomething _loading = true; and at the _loading = false; Fields without data is showing for short and then only the spinner.

I've published my answer project to my Github site.
The repo has Net7 and Net8 projects.  https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO78315052
